# postfix/smtpd: warning: connect to Milter service unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock: No such file or directory

Tags: debian, email, postfix

I have problem with postfix on debian after upgrading from squeeze to wheezy.
Postfix was configured to sign messages using dkim-filter. Before update, everything was working flawlessly, now it fails on connection with service (tcp or unix sockets).
I thought that maybe it was because of debian switch to opendkim, so I removed dkim-filter and installed opendkim - same problem. I even tried setting unix file socket connection instead of tcp option - same problem:

`postfix/smtpd: warning: connect to Milter service unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock: No such file or directory`

or (with tcp/ip):

`postfix/cleanup: warning: connect to Milter service inet:localhost:8891: Connection refused`

I checked twice - socket file exists and service was listening on port 8891.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

1. Check if opendkim is running. (I assume it is as you saw the socket file.)
2. Did you configure opendkim? The configuration file is `/etc/opendkim.conf`.

   You need to update the file to match your site/domain and **dkim.key** path.
3. Add postfix to opendkim group

   If opendkim.sock permission is as follow

   ```
   $ ls -l /var/run/opendkim

   -rw-rw-r-- 1 opendkim opendkim 6 May  2 14:56 opendkim.pid
   srwxrwxr-x 1 opendkim opendkim 0 May  2 14:56 opendkim.sock
   ```

   If Not, make sure `UMask` is set to `0002` in `/etc/opendkim.conf`.

   Then do the following

   ```
   sudo adduser postfix opendkim
   ```
4. Postfix running in chroot

   Modify `/etc/default/opendkim`, change **SOCKET** option to postfix chroot location

   ```
   SOCKET="local:/var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock"
   ```

   You will have to create directory `/var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim` and change its permission

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim
   sudo chown opendkim:opendkim /var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim
   ```
5. Restart opendkim

   ```
   sudo service opendkim restart
   ```

Comment: I found a similar problem caused by overly restrictive permissions on the opendkim directory.

Comment: I'm sure I had opendkim working before, but noticed that it wasn't working after upgrading from Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10. Updating socket path in `/etc/default/opendkim` to the same one I had already defined in `/etc/opendkim.conf` fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: my problem is I'm running postfix in chroot and I'm using unix socket. If you see  ``No such file or directory`` that mean postfix cannot find the path, but it looked for the socket inside /var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim/, not /var/run/opendkim

Comment: @HVNSweeting Isn't that covered in (4)?

Comment: it is,  that why I comment and upvoted instead of create new answer. The question contains so many problems, because if opendkim configured properly, then TCP socket should work. Thank you

Comment: Changing UMask to 002 was the key for me.

Comment: Clarify you only want the opendkim confs to point to local:/var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock Postfix wants to be configured to point at local:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock

Answer (score 19):

Quick summary that helped me to fix this warning on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:
Postfix version 3.1.0-3ubuntu0.2
Opendkim version 2.10.3-3build1

- (I assume that Postfix and Opendkim are already installed, integrated
  with each other and the only warning you are getting is 'connect to Milter service local:/var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock: No such file or directory')
- Add user postfix to group opendkim (skip if already done)

> sudo adduser postfix opendkim

- Create directory and set owner  (skip if already done)

> sudo mkdir -p /var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim
>
> sudo chown opendkim:opendkim /var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim

- Check permissions:

> ls -l /var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim
>
> ```
> srwxrwxr-x 1 opendkim opendkim 0 Nov 12 14:34 opendkim.sock
> ```

- Edit opendkim configuration files:
  /etc/opendkim.conf, add line

> Socket local:/var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock

/etc/defaults/opendkim, add

> SOCKET="local:/var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock"

- Edit postfix configuration:
  /etc/postfix/main.cf

> ```
> # Milter configuration
> # Postfix ≥ 2.6 milter_protocol = 6, Postfix ≤ 2.5 milter_protocol = 2
> milter_protocol = 6
> milter_default_action = accept
> smtpd_milters = unix:var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
> non_smtpd_milters = unix:var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
> ```

- Restart services (or reboot)

> systemctl restart opendkim
>
> systemctl restart postfix

That's it. I don't know why it's necessary to write

> smtpd_milters = unix:var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock

instead of

> smtpd_milters =
>   local:/var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock

.
 If somebody knows, explanations are welcome.

Comment: If postfix runs with CHROOT, then the config paths are relative to that. You would end up with postfix trying to resolve  `/var/spool/postfix/var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock`

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same issue on Debian stretch, which turned out to be caused by a broken systemd service file for opendkim. See this answer for a solution: https://serverfault.com/a/847442/84962

This fix boils down to:

```
/lib/opendkim/opendkim.service.generate
systemctl daemon-reload
service opendkim restart
```

Comment: I have Ubuntu system, where only this advise helped, while everything else did not work.

Comment: I run 16.04 and /lib/opendkim/opendkim.service.generate doesn't exists

Comment: Work fine on Ubuntu 18.04. Thank you.

Comment: This solved my problem on Debian 9.

Answer (score 2):

```
smtpd_milters = unix:var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock, unix:var/run/opendmarc/opendmarc.sock
non_smtpd_milters = unix:var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock, unix:var/run/opendmarc/opendmarc.sock

usermod -G opendkim,opendmarc
```

Comment: This would be a much better answer if it included some explanation of *How* and *Why* this answers the question.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to disable the `chroot`, this has security implications:

> vi /etc/postfix/master.cf

```
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
```

The warnings says `postfix/cleanup`, so you can deactivate the chroot for this service.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem because OpenDKIM and Postfix work with the rights of different users and write and read from the same socket.

I added postfix user to opendkim group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G opendkim postfix
```

Answer (score 1):

> postfix/smtpd: warning: connect to Milter service
> unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock: No such file or directory

**Far as this error goes in 2023... postfix is chrooted and expects files paths to be relative to the postfix chroot-root directory.**

> main.cf

```
# Milter configuration
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = local:opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
```

Answer (score 0):

connect to Milter service with error:

```
unix:/clamav/clamav-milter.ctl: Permission denied
```

This file:

```
ls -l /var/spool/postfix/clamav
srw-rw---- 1 clamav clamav 0 Apr  4 17:59 clamav-milter.ctl
```

shows:

```
user clamav
MilterSocketGroup postfix
MilterSocketMode 660
```

user permissions for the milter

```
chown postfix:postfix /var/spool/postfix/clamav/clamav-milter.ctl
```

Works for me

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by switching from pid to socket. Add the following two statements in respective files then restart both postfix and opendkim

.........Add this single line here regarding the smtpd_milters...

/etc/postfix/main.cf

smtpd_milters           = inet:127.0.0.1:8891

## Unrelated... Other stuff I have in this file you might need...

non_smtpd_milters       = $smtpd_milters
milter_default_action   = accept
milter_protocol   = 2
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
policyd-spf_time_limit = 3600

## THEN....... in this file...

/etc/opendkim.conf

Add this line....

Socket  inet:8891@localhost

## Both lines replacing whatever you had

Answer (score 0):

I've got this problem for a long time and used a lot of tutorials to fix it.
And now i've found the correction !!
I'm posting my config file here and my solution for people who need help like me and also if i've got the same problem an other time.

**My solution was :**
Add `127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost` to **/etc/hosts** and reboot your server.

You can find here all of my postfix config, you can try to copy it. I used two tutorials to configure my postfix server and opendkim server : https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql/ and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-dkim-with-postfix-on-debian-wheezy

**Config file : `/etc/default/opendkim`**

```
# Command-line options specified here will override the contents of
# /etc/opendkim.conf. See opendkim(8) for a complete list of options.
#DAEMON_OPTS=""
# Change to /var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim to use a Unix socket with
# postfix in a chroot:
#RUNDIR=/var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim
RUNDIR=/var/run/opendkim
#
# Uncomment to specify an alternate socket
# Note that setting this will override any Socket value in opendkim.conf
# default:
#SOCKET=local:$RUNDIR/opendkim.sock
SOCKET=inet:12301@localhost
# listen on all interfaces on port 54321:
#SOCKET=inet:54321
# listen on loopback on port 12345:
#SOCKET=inet:12345@localhost
# listen on 192.0.2.1 on port 12345:
#SOCKET=inet:12345@192.0.2.1
USER=opendkim
GROUP=opendkim
PIDFILE=$RUNDIR/$NAME.pid
EXTRAAFTER=
```

**Config file : `/etc/opendkim.conf`**

```
Syslog                  yes
UMask                   002
Socket                  inet:12301@localhost
PidFile               /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
OversignHeaders         From
TrustAnchorFile       /usr/share/dns/root.key
Canonicalization        relaxed/simple

ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts           refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
KeyTable                refile:/etc/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable            refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable

Mode                    sv
PidFile                 /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
SignatureAlgorithm      rsa-sha256

UserID                  opendkim:opendkim
```

**System file : `/lib/systemd/system/opendkim.service`**

```
Description=OpenDKIM DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter
Documentation=man:opendkim(8) man:opendkim.conf(5) man:opendkim-genkey(8) man:opendkim-genzone(8) man:opend$
After=network.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
UMask=0002
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/opendkim -P /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid -p inet:12301@localhost
Restart=on-failure
ExecReload=/bin/kill -USR1 $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I hope i could help you !