# opendkim.sock file not being created or does not exist

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot, opendkim

I'm attempting to configure opendkim on my raspberry email server that has a dovecot/postfix setup already configured.

I have followed some tutorials and some forum posts to further diagnose my issue.
Excerpt from my syslog:

```
Apr 16 08:55:06 raspberrypi postfix/smtpd[24384]: warning: connect to Milter service unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock: No such file or directory
```

When I go to check if the file exists. It is not there. This leads me to believe that either my `opendkim.conf` file is either being ignored, or there is a permissions issue. However i have not been able to resolve this with my attempts.

[Tutorial I Followed](https://habilisbest.com/raspberry-pi-as-a-personal-email-server-additional-improvements)

Below is a question I referenced

[unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock: No such file or directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74477/postfix-smtpd-warning-connect-to-milter-service-unix-var-run-opendkim-opendki)

I can't find the forum post that lead me to believe that this is an OS issue (Raspbian/Stretch), however there was one out there dated at SEP 2017

Another post I tried:

https://serverfault.com/questions/796742/connect-to-milter-service-unix-var-run-opendkim-opendkim-sock-no-such-file-or

**EDIT 1:**

The result of attempting to manually start the opendkim.service

```
Apr 18 15:49:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 18 15:49:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 18 15:49:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 18 15:49:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped OpenDKIM DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter.
Apr 18 15:49:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 18 15:49:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenDKIM DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter.
Apr 18 15:49:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 18 15:49:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Is the `opendkim` server process running?  That creates the socket that postfix talks to.

Comment: It is not, it fails to start. Then returns the error from my syslog

Comment: The error you show is coming from postfix and is a consequence of opendkim not starting.  You need to debug the opendkim process.

Comment: Are you saying there should be an error coming from opendkim instead? I'm attempting to debug why the .sock file is not being generated.

Comment: You need to manually start opendkim.  Postfix will not automatically start it.

Comment: I have updated the question with the result of attempting to manually start the service. There is no clear cut answer for the reason for the failure, which is why i went to the syslog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving my issues. There were a plethora of issues riddled throughout my `/etc/default/opendkim.conf` file. Mainly misspellings. (Result of following a tutorial, as I wasn't careful)

My main issue was that my opendkim service was not running. **The service should still run even if your dkim is not signing your messages.**

For those having similar issues, id like to recommend referring to **ALL** of your log files. Some issues may stem from parent issues, as well as some logs may give you a better idea for what the root problem is or even a better description.

See these below logs...

```
/var/log/syslog
/var/log/daemon.log
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/mail.log
```

Some of these logs can be very length, so make sure you are looking at the newest entries, as well as testing your problem and verifying with a close timestamp.